# Why does google recommend putting Analytics Asynchronous code *after* scripts in <head>?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Why does google recommend putting js scripts in  before the analytics asynchronous tracking code in your html?
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncMigrationExamples.html

Here's the quote:

> "Note: To ensure the most streamlined operation of the asynchronous snippet with respect to other scripts, we recommend you place other scripts in your site in one of these ways:
>   before the tracking code snippet in the  section of your HTML"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asynchronous analytics snippet's job is to load a more intensive script that inspects the user's browser for all sorts of information to identify them, so it can report back to the analytics server. However, since all this analytics data is not crucial to the usability of the page, Google wishes to run it at the browser's convenience.

In theory, they could advise the programmer to add the asynchronous snippet to the very bottom of the page, as the last element of the body. However, in order to allow the programmer to capture UI events to send to analytics, they want to make the the `_gaq` variable for use early on. For example, you might have a button: `<button onclick="_gaq.push(...)">Track</button>`. By making `_gaq` available early on, the small bit of code in the asynchronous snippet will queue up these messages and the heavier `ga.js` will send them off to the server later.

Now, some [implementation details](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script#attr-async): `ga.js` is loaded by adding a new `<script>` element to the document head with the `async` attribute set. IE and WebKit will asynchronously load `<script>` tags inserted from scripts. Firefox and Opera will honor the `async` attribute and also load the script asynchronously. Either way, `ga.js` is asynchronously loaded, at the browser's convenience.

Finally, once `ga.js` is executed, without blocking the page rendering due to the asynchronous loading, it can do the heavy work of collecting all of the user's data and any messages in the `_gaq` queue and send them to the server.

**Summary:** This approach uses a small inline script that initializes some key variables like `_gaq` that your page can access before the full `ga.js` script is ready. This small script also dynamically adds a `<script src="ga.js">` tag to the document in such a way that most browsers will download and execute it asynchronously, without blocking the rendering of the page or the evaluation of critical scripts.

Comment: I actually downvoted this response initially but after reading and re-reading it again it makes sense ... this was the part that set off the light bulb for me ... "Finally, once ga.js is executed, without blocking the page rendering due to the asynchronous loading, it can do the heavy work of collecting all of the user's data and any messages in the _gaq queue and send them to the server" ... so I'm basically if you put the scripts at the bottom of the page, you're saying to google that you don't mind the scripts being loaded AFTER the page so go ahead and load analytics before them too!

Answer (score 2):

As the browser loads the page, it does so from top to bottom.  Browsers have a limited number of "connections" it can use to load externally linked documents. If you put their script above yours, your own scripts might not be loaded until theirs is complete. The analytic code is not critical to the functionality of the page, so we can save it for the very last.

Comment: But google touts its the dependability of its servers, going as far as to recommend that users not serve ga.js locally, because its optimized and probably cached in user's browsers the world over ... it doesn't make sense to me that this would be the case, especially as it loads in parallel and doesn't block like other scripts.

Comment: The "in parallel" concept is limited by the number of threads a browser can devote to asynchronous requests for linked files.  Firefox, IIRC, is capped at 6.  No matter how fast Google's server is, it is still limited (in this case) by the speed of the CLIENT connection as their browser loads the page and all the associated documents.  So let's say the user has dial-up - you want your scripts loading before Google Analytics, since your scripts **might** affect usability and Google's **certainly** does not, and it might be **minutes** before the next asynch thread is open.

Comment: ^ If that's the case then why does it recommend (in that same link) that you put these scripts "*after* both the tracking code snippet and all page content (e.g. at the bottom of the HTML body)"?

Comment: Either load it before everything, or after everything.  The "before everything" route puts a lot of faith in the availability of Google's servers (probably a safe bet).  I think the key is that they want you to put it at one extreme end of the page or the other.  This isn't a **YOU MUST** proposition, it is a "you should".  This is secondarily an effort to establish some uniformity in the way webmasters include the script, rather than willy-nilly.

Comment: That's my point ... I'm trying to understand the rationale behind it. Why didn't they recommend loading it last after the js files in the instance that it loads after all the content? CSS files are still loading in the head so why shift only js files to the end of the page? I want to understand the logic of their advice.

Comment: I don't think anyone here on this site is qualified to explain the rationale behind Google's best practice suggestions beyond what I have already attempted to do.  The CSS goes at the top, even though it is subject to the same asynch limitation as the JS, because it affects the page appearance.  Load them at the bottom and you see a flash of unstyled page before the CSS is loaded.  JS affects after-load functionality, thus one can put it at the bottom of the page without visible effect.  In the case of CSS, you're balancing page load speed with aesthetics.