# Are Google and Clicky Analytics better on cloudflare or on the main website?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, cloudflare

I have a website that is under cloudflare and I am using Clicky Analytics and Google Analytics to track visitors (I have already setup the correct IP information using the Cloudflare Wordpress plugin) and I was thinking about where to place the analytics codes for better perfomance: if it is better to keep it on my site or use the cloudflare App platform.

Anybody has a clue about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good thing about our app integrations is that we can make sure the code is added to all of your pages. We will add our code near the head for our app integrations to work...so nothing needs to be configured on your end using the integration.

The only bad thing, really, is that some of the custom options Google offers for GA won't work with our app integration. Ours is really only for when you are using one UA code on the site, not if you're using multiple UA codes for other things (separate codes for subdomains,for example).

Comment: I am using it basic. So it seems to be cool by keeping it on cloudflare. Anyway for clicky I had to do the site one since Clicky integration is not free.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare optimizes their GA plugin well and follows best practice. As long as you're loading it [async in the head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4963722/94668), you're good. IMO You should instead be asking yourself which place lets you configure it most easily and spend your optimization time on other efforts.

As always, be sure to test using [RUM data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15903123/94668) and with [pagespeed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

Comment: Actually I keep GA on cloudflare and clicky on the site since it is free. Tahnk you for your answer anyway.